# dstack for creating a 3d array from 2d arrays

Tags: python

I have two 2-d Arrays -- 3x3 (new_arr_type) and 4x3 elements as shown below:

```
[[8 0 0]
[6 0 0]
[5 0 0]]
```

I assume rows as X and columns as Y

The 4x3 is:

```
[[1 0 0]
[3 0 0]
[7 0 0]
[2 0 0]]
```

I am trying to add along each X, the entire 4x3 matrix (new_train_arr) resulting in 3x3x4 matrix.
I dont know how to do this in one swoop.
I am trying dstack for each row of 4x3 matrix and adding them onto my 3x3 row by row.

`new_arr_type=np.dstack((new_arr_type[0,:,:],new_train_arr[0,:]));`
I get the shape (1,3,2) but I was expecting (1,3,3) so that I can continue stacking rows over rows along the Z axis till I have the entire 4x3 over each row of 3x3.

Maybe there is a better way. Please advise.